# Export files from Sharepoint 2007. Without stsadm(?)

Tags: 2007, powershell, stsadm

I want to export all documents from a sharepoint 2007 without have to import them to a new site. I've used the STSADM command and obviously got stuck with 50k .dat files. 
What i've understood i cant use any powershell scripts because its not supported in MOSS 2007. (atleast not Get-SPWeb). 
I've also read that u can use "open in exporer" to move your files and export them. Well that option dosent work.
Also tried a bunch of 3rd party softwares that could do the job but sadly dose not support .NET versions lower than 4.0 and i got 3.5

It would be great if i also could get the files exported with the existing file structure.

I would appreciate help alot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of documents you would like to download from a csv or database you can use System.Net.WebClient to download the documents based on URL.

```
$clnt = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$clnt.UseDefaultCredentials=$true
foreach ($doc in $doclist)
{   
    $clnt.DownloadFile($downloadURL, $DestinationPath)
}
if($clnt){$clnt.Dispose()}
```

In our case we wrote a query against the sharepoint databases to get a list of the documents we wanted...